# c# How do i use a SqlParameters as table or column names?

Tags: t-sql

How can i use a SQLParameter as as the table name and column name?

```
SELECT * FROM @TableName Where @ColumName=@Value
```

I get errors when i try to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to use dynamic sql, which is generally not recommended.

Basically, you'd have to treat your sql like a string, append the variable values you want to include in the sql, then use exec sql to execute it.

Comment: Won't work unless concatenating strings - dynamic SQL will enclose the names in single quotes

Comment: maybe I should have said 'concatenate' instead of 'append'.  I meant by using the + operator.

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic SQL](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1160) -

```
declare @TableName as varchar(20)
declare @ColumnName as varchar(20)
declare @Value as varchar(20)
declare @dynsql as varchar(200)
--Set the values before
SET @dynsql='Select * from '+@TableName+'Where '+@ColumnName+'='+@Value
execute(@dynsql)
```